# Laravel migration: “Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-migrations

My migration fails when I try to execute `php artisan migrate` or `php artisan migrate:refresh` with this error:

```
errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"
```

**Code**

*Users Table (migrated successfully)*

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('id',)->primary();
        $table->string('name', 255);
        $table->string('surname', 255);
        $table->string('email', 255)->unique();
        $table->string('password', 255);
        $table->string('profile_image', 255);
        $table->string('profile_cover', 255);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->char('token', 255)->unique()->nullable()->default(null);
        $table->enum('role', ['user', 'driver', ',merchant', 'storemanager', 'storeoperator', 'company', 'employee']);
        $table->dateTime('created');
        $table->dateTime('updated');
    });
}
```

*Address Table (fails with error)*

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('address', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('id')->primary();
        $table->string('address1');
        $table->string('address2');
        $table->string('city');
        $table->integer('country')->unsigned();
        $table->decimal('latitude');
        $table->decimal('longitude');
        $table->string('instructions');
        $table->integer('default');
        $table->integer('user')->unsigned();
        $table->dateTime('created');
        $table->dateTime('updated');
        $table->foreign('country')->references('id')->on('country')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->foreign('user')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade');

    });
}
```

Comment: Which laravel version you are using?

Comment: same question to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the reasons to work with a framework such as Laravel is syntactic sugar. By following their conventions, you write less code and have to think about fewer of the "nuts and bolts" of your application.

You are doing the opposite of this, and are already seeing the consequences. You will experience so much more pain once you try setting up models and their relationships. Instead you should be using a migration that looks like this:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateAddressesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        // table names are plural of the object name
        Schema::create('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            // automatically create an incrementing bigint column called 'id'
            $table->id();
            // name foreign ID columns correctly to save yourself trouble later
            $table->foreignId('country_id')->constrained();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
            // specify lengths for your varchar columns
            $table->string('address1', 100);
            $table->string('address2', 100);
            $table->string('city', 100);
            $table->decimal('latitude');
            $table->decimal('longitude');
            $table->string('instructions', 100);
            $table->integer('default');
            // why would you define your own timestamp columns with non-standard names?
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}
```

And the `users` table; you'd want to update its migration similarly.

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            // DO NOT use an enum column; create another table called roles instead
            $table->foreignId('role_id')->constrained();
            $table->string('name', 100);
            $table->string('surname', 100);
            $table->string('email', 100)->unique();
            $table->string('password', 255);
            $table->string('profile_image', 255);
            $table->string('profile_cover', 255);
            $table->rememberToken();
            // 
            $table->char('token', 255)->unique()->nullable()->default(null);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Will look into this before getting deep into the project. Thanks for the advice miken32

Comment: Please do, you'll save yourself a trip back here in a week wondering why you can't select any models, or your timestamp columns aren't updating, or your relations aren't working. All of these basic functions will need overrides and workarounds in the model definition if you continue on your present course.

Comment: You rescued me with this post. Thanks Mike! Setting up those foreign keys so Eloquent and Nova relationships work correctly was eluding me, especially since I use multi-word table names.

Answer (score 0):

The data types on each table must match exactly for the keyed columns. On `users`, id is a signed integer, on `address`, user is an unsigned integer. I would suggest using unsigned integers for the id since it should never go negative, and gives you a higher upper limit.

Comment: it worked like magic, thanks. Don't have enough reputation yet to give it a thumbs up.

Answer (score 0):

In you `address` migration instead of:

```
$table->integer('user')->unsigned();
```

Put:

```
$table->integer('user');
```

Both the FK and the reference key should be the same type.

Comment: Fixed and worked like magic thanks ml59. Totally overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

you can change id of table users to:

```php
$table->id();
```

and change in ADress table `user` to `user_id` and try to change foreign id like this:

```php
$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: Was indeed caused by incorrectly formed foreign keys. On address I had ->unsigned() but the column I was referencing did not have ->unsigned() . Thanks for the answer and welcome to Stackoverflow Morani

Comment: thank you! :) but this syntax is working good too. You can try it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it failed is as @aynber mentioned. The key's data type must match.

It is also important to follow Laravel best practice for naming primary key and foreign key. The primary key should be 'id' and foreign key should be table name (singular) underscore id. For example if the table name is users then the foreign key for table users should be 'user_id'.

Here is the example for table addresses (plural)

```
    Schema::create('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        ...

        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
    });
```

You don't have to provide the table name or the primary key of another table because Laravel will figure that out from foreign key (user_id translates to table users with primary key id). Later on, when you create an eloquent model you can leave several information from your model.

```
    class Address {

        public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
        }
    }
```

Here you don't have to specify `$table` property and also you don't have to provide the foreign key or primary key in `belongsTo` method.